# Python 3.x - Error while installing packages using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've got a problem while I want to install couple packages for python 3.4.

The problem appears while I want to type `pip`. Any commands after word `pip`, `easy_install` are giving the same error. Installed `get-pip.py` before but the error still occurs:

```
C:\Users\Konrad>pip
Fatal error in launche: Job information querying failed
```

I'm running windows10 x64. The cmd was in admin mode.

Aby suggestions? I typed that error message through google, but there weren't any helpful answers.

Running `python` just works and launches Python 3.4.3.

Comment: What's the screenshot for?

Comment: @Torxed: the error message from the `pip` command, I suppose. It's text however. OP: please just copy and paste that text into your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for clarifying, I skimmed to quickly, didn't notice the two lines in the rest of the output. Cheers!

Comment: Using a development version of windows with python will probably be more hassle than it is worth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't look like the Python `pip` command. You have a *different* `pip` executable in the way somewhere.

Use `python -m pip` as a work-around; it'll use Python to find the module and use it as a command-line tool (which is explicitly supported):

```
python -m pip install <something>
```

Comment: added another answer with error message using your solution (the answer was too long).

Comment: @kodi1911: installing packages with C extensions on Windows in notoriously troublesome. See [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869), but it's usually easier to just use [Gohlke's builds](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Comment: installed visual studio 2010 express. It's working. Thank you!